# Copying File on Network Drive using Perl in Windows Server 2008

Tags: perl, windows-server-2008

How would you explore and write to windows shared directories in perl ? Note: I have the right for network drive creation on the concerned workstation. This script was working perfectly fine in Windows Server 2003 but stopped working when i upgraded the server to Windows Server 2008. 
I already have the network drive mapped to my server as M drive:

```
$prompt = *some file*
        if ($environment eq "Media") {
            $targetdir = "M:\\EAN\\Documents\\";
            print "Media Environment selected.  Using $targetdir\n";
            copy ($prompt, $targetpath) || die "Can't copy $prompt \n to $targetpath\n $!";
        }
```

When ever it tries to copy the file, the script just dies saying "Cant copy ... since the path doesnt exist". 
Why is this happening? 

Is there any solution for this? Is there any way i can authenticate a network drive in the script?

Comment: Can I suggest doing it via UNC path instead? E.g. `\\servername.domain.fqdn\sharename\path\to\files`

Comment: There is a copy, using module File::Copy. http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html

Answer (score 0):

You used $targetdir when you defined the path, but used $targetpath in the copy statement instead of $targetdir.